# Unable to revoke default privilege in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Currently, I end up a situation where default access privileges are like below

```
postgres=> \ddp
              Default access privileges
  Owner   | Schema | Type  |    Access privileges
----------+--------+-------+--------------------------
 postgres | public | table | "app"=arw/postgres+
          |        |       | dbt=arw/postgres
(1 row)
```

I used 2 below queries to revoke. They ran successfully but didn't affect

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER postgres IN SCHEMA public REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM "app";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER postgres IN SCHEMA public REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM dbt;
```

1. What is the problem with those commands?
2. Side question, what does "arw" abbreviation mean in this context?

Update:

1. I want to revoke privileges for app and dbt, which were granted permission by postgres. Following from [this discusion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114763/cannot-revoke-default-privileges-from-postgresql-user/114764#114764), I encountered with the problem with default access privileges

Comment: `FOR USER postgres`, that's the default superuser that is allowed to do anything. Even when you try to revoke it. Why do you use a superuser anyway? That's only for some very special maintenance issues, only for things you can't do with a normal user.

Comment: @FrankHeikens "*default superuser that is allowed to do anything, even when you try to revoke it*" - isn't this about revoking privileges from the `app` and `dbt` roles, which would be granted to them by default when the default superuser (`postgres`) creates new tables?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. What is the problem with those commands?

You are attempting to revoke privileges from the `postgres` user (as specified in your `FOR USER postgres` clause).  The `postgres` user is the superuser, (like `root` is the superuser for your `*nix` operating system) -- you wouldn't want to revoke access to this user anyways, or else how would you go about granting access to anyone else?  It is better to `CREATE USER` and then perform the `REVOKE` against that user.

2. Side question, what does "arw" abbreviation mean in this context?

The `arw` are flags indicating what permissions users have:

- `a` stands for `APPEND`, which means the user is granted the `INSERT` command.
- `r` stands for `READ`, which means the user is granted the `SELECT` command.
- `w` stands for `WRITE`, which means the user is granted the `UPDATE` command.

Therefore, you'll see that the `"app"` user is granted `arw` and the `dbt` user is granted `arw` (side note -- the `app` user is in double quotes because you indicated it [must be referenced in lowercase form](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html)).  You'll also notice that neither user is granted the `d` option, so neither will be able to `DELETE` rows from the table.

More information about these flags [can be found in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html#PRIVILEGE-ABBREVS-TABLE)